# Changing webservice reference dynamically

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I've got a webservice written in VS2008, and I'm trying to consume it with an exe written in VS2010.  I need to be able to reference the service URL dynamically from within the application.

In the past I was able to change the URL Behavior for the service from Static to Dynamic, but this is not showing up as an option for me now for some reason.  When I look at the properties for the service, the only item I see is "Folder Name".  In other projects I was able to see "Folder Name", "URL Behavior", and one other that I can't remember off the top of my head.

Does anybody know how I can change the URL programmatically if I can't change the URL Behavior to dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using  .NET 3.5 then you can specify the URL inside the  block in the app config as shown below

```
  <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/yourService.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
```